# DJI Bridge App Tutorial No Video Stream in Swift - Phantom 4 Pro

Tags: swift, video, dji-sdk

I am currently going trough DJI Bridge App Tutorial. I am using Swift with bridge header that imports VideoPreviewer. App compiles just fine. I can connect to the product. I can register. Bridging app is working fine. But I get stuck with video stream. Do you have got any ideas?

Method

"func videoFeed(_ videoFeed: DJIVideoFeed, didUpdateVideoData videoData: Data)

is called correctly. When reading bytes from Data object. I am receiving some values. Than sending these values to the VidePreviewer as

func videoFeed(_ videoFeed: DJIVideoFeed, didUpdateVideoData videoData: Data) {

```
   var result = videoData.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UInt8 in
        return pointer.pointee
    }

    print (result)


    print("Stream info:\(VideoPreviewer.instance().currentStreamInfo.frameRate)")
    VideoPreviewer.instance().push(&result, length: Int32(videoData.count))

        print(VideoPreviewer.instance().isDefaultPreviewer)




}"
```

However is this correct? DJIVideoStreamBasicInfo(frameSize: (0.0, 0.0), frameRate: 15, encoderType: 1). print (result) returns values
-----But the frameSize is 0.0, 0.0 could this be the problem?-----
Result is that View set for VideoPreviewer is always black. Below is code for whole Swift file for whole DJICameraViewController.swift, that compiles and run.

import UIKit
import DJISDK

class DJICameraViewController: UIViewController, DJISDKManagerDelegate,DJICameraDelegate,DJIBaseProductDelegate, DJIVideoFeedListener {

```
var camera: DJICamera!
@IBOutlet weak var fpvPreviewView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var recordBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var changeWorkModeSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.registerApp()
    VideoPreviewer.instance().setView(self.fpvPreviewView)



}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    VideoPreviewer.instance().setView(nil)
    DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.remove(self)
}

func registerApp(){

     DJISDKManager.registerApp(with: self)

}


func appRegisteredWithError(_ error:Error?)
{
    var message: String = "Application is registered."

    if (error != nil) {
        message = "Register App Failed!"
    } else {
        message = "Application is registered."
        DJISDKManager.enableBridgeMode(withBridgeAppIP: "192.168.2.2")
        DJISDKManager.startConnectionToProduct()
        VideoPreviewer.instance().start()


    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

/* after product is recognized. FetchCamera method is called by method productConnected */

func fetchCamera() -> DJICamera? {

    if ((DJISDKManager.product()) == nil){

        return nil
    }

    if (DJISDKManager.product()!.isKind(of: DJIAircraft.self)){

        print("Have UAV")
        return ((DJISDKManager.product() as? DJIAircraft)?.camera)!
    }

    return nil
}



/* DJIBaseProductDelegate method called when product is recognized */

func productConnected(_ product: DJIBaseProduct?) {
    print("Product recognized")
    if ((product) != nil) {
        product?.delegate = self

        camera = self.fetchCamera()
        if (camera != nil) {
            camera.delegate = self
            DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.add(self, with: nil)
        }
    }
}



func videoFeed(_ videoFeed: DJIVideoFeed, didUpdateVideoData videoData: Data) {


    var result = videoData.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> UInt8 in
        return pointer.pointee
    }

    print (result)



    print("Stream info:\(VideoPreviewer.instance().currentStreamInfo.frameRate)")
    VideoPreviewer.instance().push(&result, length: Int32(videoData.count))

        print(VideoPreviewer.instance().isDefaultPreviewer)



}
```

}

From the Xcode console following code prints outputs below

```
`print("Stream info:\(videoPreview.currentStreamInfo.frameRate)")
    VideoPreviewer.instance().push(&result, length: Int32(videoData.count))
       print(videoPreview.currentStreamInfo)
        print(videoPreview.isDefaultPreviewer)`
```

Output printed by the print code above:

Start:

```
Stream info:0
DJIVideoStreamBasicInfo(frameSize: (0.0, 0.0), frameRate: 0, encoderType: 0)
true
136
```

2nd:

```
Stream info:0
[h264 @ 0x102024210] sps_id 32 out of range
VUI timing infomation not present, set to default:29.97fps
[h264 @ 0x102024210] sps_id 32 out of range
VUI timing infomation not present, set to default:29.97fps
[h264 @ 0x102024210] missing picture in access unit with size 958351
DJIVideoStreamBasicInfo(frameSize: (0.0, 0.0), frameRate: 0, encoderType: 0)
true
65
```

3rd:

```
Stream info:15
DJIVideoStreamBasicInfo(frameSize: (0.0, 0.0), frameRate: 15, encoderType: 1)
true
119
```

And sometimes pops up:

```
Stream info:15
[h264 @ 0x102024210] SEI type 103 size 1712 truncated at 288
[h264 @ 0x102024210] sps_id 32 out of range
VUI timing infomation not present, set to default:29.97fps
[h264 @ 0x102024210] missing picture in access unit with size 111113
DJIVideoStreamBasicInfo(frameSize: (0.0, 0.0), frameRate: 15, encoderType: 
[h264 @ 0x102024810] SEI type 103 size 1712 truncated at 279
```

And other times pops-up:

```
 Stream info:15
DJIVideoStreamBasicInfo(frameSize: (0.0, 0.0), frameRate: 15, encoderType: 1)
[h264 @ 0x102024810] sps_id 32 out of range
true
[h264 @ 0x102024810] sps_id 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x102024810] sps_id 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x102024810] sps_id 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x102024810] sps_id 32 out of range
0[h264 @ 0x102024810] 
 sps_id 32 out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set the VideoPreview.instance() as a let somewhere convenient and use it.

Also, make sure to provide a valid queue when adding the listener to the video feed.

Try these and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. I have added

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. I have added  let videoPreview:VideoPreviewer = VideoPreviewer.instance() and using it. But unfortunately no change. Also it takes some time until app receives frame-rate of 15fps. Same as before. I extended my question with more info from console